# Iptables forward traffic from A to B where A is not gateway for B

Tags: iptables, port-forwarding

I want to forward ssh traffic from A port 2222 to B port 22. I do have ipv4 forwarding set to 1 on both interfaces. Still, this does not work. What is wrong?

Machine A:
eth0 `192.168.0.150`
eth1 `217.27.166.110`

Machine B:
eth0 `192.168.0.200`

`iptables -L`:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp echo-request

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             192.168.0.200        tcp dpt:ssh state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

`iptables -L -t nat`:

```
root@lbpub01:~# iptables -L -tnat
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             217.27.166.110       tcp dpt:2222 to:192.168.0.200:22

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  217.27.166.110       192.168.0.200        tcp dpt:ssh

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

**Update**

I got help from the nice guys at irc@freenode, so here is my working `iptables-save` file:

```
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp -d 217.27.166.110 --dport 2222 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.200:22
-A POSTROUTING -o eth+ -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
COMMIT
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport http -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j DROP
COMMIT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been working on this same problem for a while now.  The solution that seems to work for me (at least when I demoed it using VMs) wound up looking significantly different than what you have posted here.

Real quick, here are my configurations:

`iptables -L`:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

`iptables -S`:

```
-P INPUT DROP
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

(Just to clarify, that last INPUT rule is to allow ssh access into Machine A.)

`iptables -t nat -L`:
`Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:2222 to:192.168.0.200:22`

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
SNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:22 to:217.27.166.110

`iptables -t nat -S`:

```
-P PREROUTING ACCEPT
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-P POSTROUTING ACCEPT
-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 2222 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.200:22
-A POSTROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j SNAT --to-source 217.27.166.110
```

---

So, interestingly, I didn't need anything in the FORWARD chain, but it appears that the PREROUTING rule was enough to get the first packet from the client forwarded to Machine B.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i <external_interface> -p <tcp/udp> --dport <port_to_accept_connections_through> -j DNAT --to <destination_address:destination_port>
```

The problem, then, was the response packet getting lost by going through the Gateway.  I didn't realize this until I Wiresharked the eth1 on Machine A and noticed that the source address on the packet bound for Machine B was still that of the client machine.  I then used the POSTROUTING table to change the source address to Machine A's IP address on eth1 so that Machine B would know to send the response to Machine A and not the Gateway.

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p <tcp/udp> --dport <destination_port> -j SNAT --to <internal_IP_address_of_machine_a>
```

At this point, I was able to establish the connection from a client sitting on the same network as Machine A's eth0 interface to Machine B.  While I'm not 100% sure how the firewall knew what to do with the response packets sent from Machine B to the client machine, I think the most likely reason is the rule in the INPUT chain that allows established connections through the firewall:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: I forgot about this question. I should have posted my solution which I finally managed to make, with help from the nice guys at freenode. You solution differs a bit from mine but I think they work similarly. For reference, here is my iptables --save: http://pastebin.com/gXM2uwwx